# FileUpload works well locally but not well as I publish the project to the server

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've developed a web app using asp.net c#. There is a `FileUpload` Control that may upload pdf or word file. But as I published the website, it is not working properly! While on the local version no problem seen. I've been trying the following:

```
if (FileUpload1.PostedFile != null)
{
    string fn = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(empDL.client_id + FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
    if (FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Documents/" + fn)));
        empDL.uploadedfile = fn;
    }
}
```

Comment: check whether the `Documents` folder is created or not, if not then create that folder.

Comment: What's the exception you're getting? If you're not getting any, focus on your error handling first (ELMAH maybe?).

Comment: Make sure you have the permissions to read the folder, for this check your server folder where you want to upload file.

Comment: This is probably a permission error. Find out if the app pool user has write permissions on the documents folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it is because that Documents folder hasn't write permission, you can set every one permission for this folder and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
First make sure you have created your folder (although the code also checks for that) and you have permission to access that folder.

```
string Fileloc = "/" + "Content/Upload/YourFolder/";

if (FileUpload1.PostedFile!=null)
{
    if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(Fileloc))
    {
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Fileloc);
    }
    var path = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(Fileloc), FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
    FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(path);
}
```

let me know if it has solved your problem or not.